# CursorLoader loading contacts - Android

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-cursorloader

I'm using code below, and load contats. All is well, when contacts size less than 100. I use tab, where switch fragments. And when click on tab with contact, i get the delay.But i use CursorLoader, and do not understand why there is a delay.

Using this class to load contacts (ContactFetcher.fetchAll();)

UPDATE!

There is a way to upload contacts using the LoaderManager, with list phone number (if the contact has more than one) and list email? It would be great with an example)

Here is code:

```
public class ContactFetcher {
    private Context context;

    public ContactFetcher(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    public ArrayList<MainContact> fetchAll() {
        ArrayList<MainContact> listContacts = new ArrayList<MainContact>();
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context, RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, // the columns to retrieve (all)
                null, // the selection criteria (none)
                null, // the selection args (none)
                null // the sort order (default)
        );

        Cursor c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MainContact contact = loadContactData(c);
                listContacts.add(contact);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return listContacts;
    }

    private MainContact loadContactData(Cursor c) {
        // Get Contact ID
        int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        String contactId = c.getString(idIndex);
        // Get Contact Name
        int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String contactDisplayName = c.getString(nameIndex);
        MainContact contact = new MainContact(contactId, contactDisplayName, null, null, null, true);
        fetchContactNumbers(c, contact);
        fetchContactEmails(c, contact);
        return contact;
    }

    public void fetchContactNumbers(Cursor cursor, MainContact contact) {
        // Get numbers
        final String[] numberProjection = new String[]{Phone.NUMBER, Phone.TYPE,};

        Cursor phone = new CursorLoader(context, Phone.CONTENT_URI, numberProjection,
                Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.id)}, null)
                .loadInBackground();

        if (phone.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

            while (!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                final String number = phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                final int type = phone.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                String customLabel = "Custom";
                CharSequence phoneType = Phone.getTypeLabel(
                        context.getResources(), type, customLabel);
                contact.addNumber(number, phoneType.toString());
                phone.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        phone.close();
    }

    public void fetchContactEmails(Cursor cursor, MainContact contact) {
        // Get email
        final String[] emailProjection = new String[]{Email.DATA, Email.TYPE};

        Cursor email = new CursorLoader(context, Email.CONTENT_URI, emailProjection,
                Email.CONTACT_ID + "= ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.id)}, null)
                .loadInBackground();

        if (email.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactEmailColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);
            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE);

            while (!email.isAfterLast()) {
                final String address = email.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex);
                final int type = email.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                String customLabel = "Custom";
                CharSequence emailType = Email.getTypeLabel(
                        context.getResources(), type, customLabel);
                contact.addEmail(address, emailType.toString());
                email.moveToNext();
            }

        }

        email.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `CursorAdapter`, might be moving cursor to list take time, you can use Log and check printed time to find witch operation take most time.

Comment: even better would be to just use the cursor call loadContactData(c); in the getView of the adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're not using `CursorLoader` properly.  It should not be created or used directly in a method call such as `fetchContactNumbers()` which is presumably being called from an `Activity` or `Fragment` lifecycle callback like `onResume()`.  Instead, you should use the `LoaderManager.initLoader()` method and provide a class which implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`.  In the `onCreateLoader()` callback is where you create your `CursorLoader` and in `onLoadFinished()` is where you retrieve the results.  This article will help you to understand the `Loader` framework: http://po.st/xHoVMf

Comment: It would be great example, with  downloading contacts? I think, wil be problem with contacts,  which has more than one phone numbers......

Comment: That's irrelevant - you process the results however you need in `onLoadFinished`. Right now you are not using the loader as intended, so it is still running on the main thread.

Comment: Can anyone fix my code using LoaderManager, I do not quite understand cursor work)

Comment: @GenkaKasyan, your call to the `Cursor` isn't the issue, though you could probably make it more efficient later using a `projection` and/or `selection` which refined your search instead of returning all records.  The issue is with how the `CursorLoader` is being used.  Have a look at the article I included in my answer, it has a project which shows how to use a `CursorLoader`.  It retrieves call logs rather than contacts, but the concept is exactly the same.

Comment: @Saty looks like the link shortener isn't working these days. With Android today, you likely don't want to use a `Loader` as they can be very tricky to get right, the API is quite cumbersom, and it can be done much cleaner using other architecture components such as `LiveData`. If you're still interested in the article on loaders, it is here: http://hiqes.com/android-loaders/